# multiple tomcat on same server ...ajp stops working

Tags: tomcat, ajp

I have a situation where I have several Tomcats installed on the same server in Windows. Each Tomcat has its own ports. The first listens to 8080 ajp 8009 and the second listens to 8081 ajp 8010.

My problem is: running 7 tomcats from port 8080 to 8086 works fine but ajp of the first 3 (8009,8010,8011) stop working (while they work if each Tomcat is running in isolation). It seems like no more than 4 ajp listeners can run. How can this be? Anyone can help?

Comment: How do you mean 'stops working'? Fails? Stops responding? Stops being load-balanced?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your shutdown ports don't overlap with your AJP ports.